# Performance bottleneck in writing a large matrix of doubles to a file

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

My program opens a file which contains 100,000 numbers and parses them out into a 10,000 x 10 array correlating to 10,000 sets of 10 physical parameters. The program then iterates through each row of the array, performing overlap calculations between that row and every other row in the array.

The process is quite simple, and being new to c++, I programmed it the most straightforward way that I could think of. However, I know that I'm not doing this in the most optimal way possible, which is something that I would love to do, as the program is going to face off against my cohort's identical program, coded in Fortran, in a "race".

I have a feeling that I am going to need to implement multithreading to accomplish my goal of speeding up the program, but not only am I new to c++, I am new to multithreading, so I'm not sure how I should go about creating new threads in a beneficial way, or if it is even something that would give me that much "gain on investment" so to speak.

The program has the potential to be run on a machine with over 50 cores, but because the program is so simple, I'm not convinced that more threads is necessarily better. I think that if I implement two threads to compute the complex parameters of the two gaussians, one thread to compute the overlap between the gaussians, and one thread that is dedicated to writing to the file, I could speed up the program significantly, but I could also be wrong.

CODE:

```
cout << "Working...\n";

double **gaussian_array;
gaussian_array = (double **)malloc(N*sizeof(double *));
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    gaussian_array[i] = (double *)malloc(10*sizeof(double));
}
fstream gaussians;
gaussians.open("GaussParams", ios::in);

if (!gaussians){
    cout << "File not found.";
}
else {
//generate the array of gaussians -> [10000][10]
    int i = 0;
    while(i < N) {
        char ch;
        string strNums;
        string Num;
        string strtab[10];
        int j = 0;
        getline(gaussians, strNums);
        stringstream gaussian(strNums);
        while(gaussian >> ch) {
            if(ch != ',') {
                Num += ch;
                strtab[j] = Num;
            }
            else {
                Num = "";
                j += 1;
            }
        }
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            stringstream dbl(strtab[c]);
            dbl >> gaussian_array[i][c];
        }
        i += 1;
    }
}
gaussians.close();
//Below is the process to generate the overlap file between all gaussians:
string buffer;
ofstream overlaps;
overlaps.open("OverlapMatrix", ios::trunc);
overlaps.precision(15);
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < N; j++){
        double r1[6][2];
        double r2[6][2];
        double ol[2];
        //compute complex parameters from the two gaussians
        compute_params(gaussian_array[i], r1);
        compute_params(gaussian_array[j], r2);
        //compute overlap between the gaussians using the complex parameters
        compute_overlap(r1, r2, ol);
        //write to file
        overlaps << ol[0] << "," << ol[1];
        if(j < N - 1)
            overlaps << " ";
        else
            overlaps << "\n";
    }
}
overlaps.close();
return 0;
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `while(gaussian >> ch)` loop looks like it can be solved with `getline` again by taking advantage of `getline`'s third parameter to change the delimiter you're looking for. getline(gaussian, strtab[j], ',');`

Comment: `compute_params(gaussian_array[i], r1);` looks like itt can be moved up one loop so you don't have to recompute it for every iteration of `j`. That's assuming `compute_overlap` uses `r1` without damaging it, something that cannot be determined with the given code. If it does damage `r1`, you may be better off copying `r1` that recomputing it.

Comment: Side note: Learning C++ and teaching yourself multithreading simultaneously may be tricky. Both have a LOT of caveats, and it can be hard to take a working single threaded program and migrate it to multiple threads. Often the threading needs to be baked in at the beginning or you'll find you've missed some vital-but-tiny detail.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for all of the suggestions! I had no idea that the getline function had a third argument to change the delimiter; I implemented that change into my program, as well as the suggestion to put the computation of the complex parameters for the i'th gaussian outside of the j-loop, which sped up my program by around 25%!